# Making a line move smoothly under my navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying some stuff out for webdesign but I'm having a bit of a problem with the following idea:

So I'm trying to make a litte .png line I made move smoothly under my navbar. So when I click on another link it slidestowards it and stays there as long as that site is active, but I'm having a bit of a problem finding the code, even tried making it myself.

If anybody has a usefull link for this or a code they wrote before, it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jquery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/),
or research scrollTop, scrollLeft of div and setTimeout if you want build it your self.

for example,

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        .outer {
            display: block;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .inner {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var isMoving;
        function moveRight() {
            if (!isMoving) {
                isMoving = true;
                var cnt = document.getElementById('container');
                for (var i = 1;i <= 10;i ++)
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        cnt.scrollLeft += 10;
                        if (cnt.scrollLeft % 100 == 0) isMoving = null;
                    }, 100*i);
            }
        }
        function moveLeft() {
            if (!isMoving) {
                isMoving = true;
                var cnt = document.getElementById('container');
                for (var i = 1;i <= 10;i ++)
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        cnt.scrollLeft -= 10;
                        if (cnt.scrollLeft % 100 == 0) isMoving = null;
                    }, 100*i);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" class="outer">
        <div style="width: 300px">
            <div class="inner" style="background-color: green;"></div>
            <div class="inner" style="background-color: red;"></div>
            <div class="inner" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="moveRight();">move to right</button>
    <button onclick="moveLeft();">move to left</button>
</body>
```

Regards,

ben

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow --  you should know that, in general, we like our answers to either contain specific code snippets, or [links](http://api.jquery.com/animate) to documents that do.

Comment: Ok Ben, thanks I will try it out tomorow and let you know how it worked out!